# {OSTICKET} Normal users cannot login in Chrome or Edge, but agents can!

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, webserver, php7

I am trying a ticketing system called osTicket, to see if we can implement it if we like it.

The problem is, user login only works in Firefox. Normal users cannot login in Chrome or Edge, but agents can, that's so weird!

[image]

In the photo that I added you can see that the user's tickets page loads, but I'm stuck in the login.

This is my system information (it's on the latest version of osTicket):

[image]

Comment: You can use the Chrome/Edge Developer Tools to see the requests and check if any of them are failing. You would also have some logging for the PHP component on the server side, which might provide additional information.

Comment: Both web browsers with the Developer Tools return this error: "GET http://osticket-flos.com/tickets.php 422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

Comment: Seems to be an open issue with this product: https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/issues/4654 . Apparently it's possible to work around by commenting out some lines of code, see this forum for details: https://forum.osticket.com/d/93573-error-422-unprocessable-entity-at-staff-control-panel-after-clean-install/6

Comment: Negative, I've already commented those lines of code and still doesn't work. And in Apache logs all the information is about Firefox, there's no entries about Chrome or Edge. This error is breaking my mind!!

Comment: 1) Regarding the logs, I assume you're talking about the User-Agent string, which starts with 'Mozilla/5.0...'. All browsers have that prefix for historical reasons. You'll find the actual browser name near the end of the string. 2) Regarding the main issue, you could contact the company behind this product for commercial support.

Comment: I've already tried, but their support couldn't resolve my issue and they're asking me to pay premium support for more in-depth support. What I'm gonna try it's to build the same scenario on my home with VMs, and see if I have the same issue. Could be a proxy or something that is making this error at my enterprise. I will update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, FINALLY, AFTER TWO WEEKS I GOT THE SOLUTION.

I changed the Apache MPM from **PREFORK** to **FAST_CGI**.